# Cant login in opencart admin panel

Tags: php, opencart

I have migrated opencart (1.5.6) website Bluehost to Godadday, Front-end pages working good but can not login in admin panel.

In admin panel it validating the login credentials but not redirect admin to their dashboard stay on the same page without any error.

Please help me to get rid off this issue.

Comment: define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://localhost/limeapple/admin/');
define('HTTP_CATALOG', 'http://localhost/limeapple/');
define('HTTP_IMAGE', 'http://localhost/limeapple/image/');
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'http://localhost/limeapple/admin/');
define('HTTPS_CATALOG', 'http://localhost/limeapple/');
define('HTTPS_IMAGE', 'http://localhost/limeapple/image/');

Answer (score 0):

hello brother from past few days i had same problem

- the mistake I had done was on admin panel page on which I was redirecting it back to login page

Login Page -> connection was successful -> admin Panel -> back to Login page (False condition using header)

check you admin page for such condition

Answer (score 0):

Check  your config.php in admin folder , must be some issue with path. or check php.ini in admin folder.

Comment: here is my config.php